# Do I have to repair a cracked AMOLED screen?

Tags: broken-screen

My phone recently (a couple weeks ago maybe?) slipped out of my hand when I was trying to pick it up off a table and flew across the room.  Despite having armor, the corner of the screen was smashed and there is some cracking around the smashed bit. The smashed part is around 0.4" wide and 0.3" high and is actually in the bezel, not the screen itself, but there are three cracks that cross the screen. two join together and extend across the screen 1.7" wide and 0.25" high, and the third joins one of the other cracks around midway and extends to the edge of the screen 0.7" from the bottom. Very little if any glass detached from the smashed area, and I put a screen protector over the whole thing to protect my finger which covers all but about 0.05" around the edge, although it is clear that it doesn't completely seal around the cracks (it has the shade of a bubble along the cracks edges closest to the smashed part.)

Everything still works perfectly,and as the cracks are not terribly noticeable I was planning to just keep using the phone until its end of life, as the cost to repair the device starts at nearly $300 and I still am paying for the phone.  However, in researching what it would take to repair it myself to save a couple hundred bucks (which by the way after reading I feel like I am not mechanically skilled enough to not risk damaging it and wasting a whole day trying) I found this note:

> OLEDs cease to work when exposed to oxygen or moisture, and are thus sealed in an airtight encapsulation (this is also why OLED panels turn black underneath a screen crack). There is no way to replace the front glass alone— the OLED layers are laminated to the glass.

Currently there is no screen blackening under any of the cracks (it looks darker when viewing the cracks head on but it's the crack itself, at an angle I can see the pixels are all white underneath).  But I am concerned whether the screen *will* start turning black at some point.  If so, how long will it take before it first appears, and at what rate will it blacken?  How much of the screen will it affect?  From what I have read, since a new OLED comes with a replacement screen it won't have any bearing on the repair, but I would like to decide now whether or not to keep the phone - if it will have to repaired in the near future it might be better to just sell it now while it still has some value, as currently it would (inexplicably!) actually be cheaper just to pay off the phone and sell it with a broken screen than to try to repair it, while in the future the repair price will remain the same but the value of the phone will only go down.

Comment: You have my vote for the efforts you have put here, but please know that the question is Android independent, hence, off-topic here. Perhaps, Reddit and XDA would prove to be a better place for this question. :)